# Setting tab size in TableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, text

I have a class which extends `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, which renders strings in a monospace font, with a particular color. By default, it appears that tabs are not rendered at all (0 spaces). How can I set the tab size and/or cause them to be rendered?

**edits:**
By "tabs" I mean tab characters, which I would just like to be rendered as some number of spaces. Rewriting the string is an option, but I figured there was a better way.

Comment: What tabs?  There are no tabs in a table cell.

Comment: Your comment is older than the (unedited) question.  How is this possible?

Comment: Oh wait, he means "tab characters" - I thought he meant jtabbedpane tabs.

Answer (score 3):

[`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) is a [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) and does what a `JLabel` will do. I suggest you make yourself a custom [`TableCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and return a `JPanel` with two or more `JLabel`s laid out appropriately. Alternatively use a [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) that overrides [`paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) to draw as you wish.

Note: attempting to use HTML in renderers is a really bad idea performance wise.

Comment: Exactly why and when is using HTML a bad idea, performance wise? Presumably you have some hard and fast rules?

Comment: Just to clarify; we have JTables with >100,000 rows and renderers which make heavy use of HTML, tables, fonts, colors and all.

Comment: Each time getTableCellRenderer is called, HTML is set on the JLabel, parsed and all the behind the scenes stuff is done. That tends to be really slow.

Comment: does DefaultTableCellRenderer actually do HTML-like stuff, a la JTextPane? When I said font and color, I just meant that I call setFont() and setBackground() to get the monospace font and appropriate background color.

Comment: Yeah, just start the label text off with <html>, as with other JLabels.

Answer (score 0):

Half baked answer: replace them with space characters, the quantity you need (need some computing if used beyond just indentation of lines).